# I need a software to create a image and text file, with multi level submenus that zoom into the next

Tags: presentation, visual-design

The closest I have found for my answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41938924/how-to-create-apple-watch-menu-style-web# ( view the code snippet from codepen ). I consider that as the first submenu.

I picture that a one paged dynamic website may work in the same manner as this, however I do not want HTML as the end product. The end product I am trying to create is something like an 'adaptive' presentation file. I don't know if such a file format exists.

The visuals: For each menu one clicks, a radial show of the new submenus pop up, and the view of page shifts and centers around the new submenu (instead of looking like it loaded a new page).